# When does a iOS touches method (Cancelled & Ended) called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touches, touchesended, touchescancelled

I'm trying to write a program using UIBezierPath and touches Methods.
I am confused by two touches method:

```
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

I don't understand when these method are called or how can I call them. At first I thought they both were the same, until I read somewhere that they weren't. Question is: How can I call one of these methods and how are they different from one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call these methods. They are called by *Cocoa* framework for you. You just need to implement them to provide correct (the native one) behaviour o your subclass of `UIResponser` or your custom `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass.

Please refer to [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW16) about subclassing `UIResponder` for more details about how you should implement these methods.

From [Apple's documentation](http://Tells%20the%20responder%20when%20one%20or%20more%20fingers%20are%20raised%20from%20a%20view%20or%20window.) about `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method:

> Tells the responder when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesCancelled:withEvent:) about `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method:

> Sent to the receiver when a system event (such as a low-memory warning) cancels a touch event.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9) from Apple give you an answer regarding the `touchesCancelled` event :

> If a responder creates persistent objects while handling events, it should implement the `touchesCancelled:withEvent`: method to dispose of those objects if the system cancels the sequence. **Cancellation occurs when an external event—for example, an incoming phone call—disrupts the current app’s event processing.** Note that a responder object should also dispose of any persistent objects when it receives the last `touchesEnded:withEvent:` message for a multitouch sequence.

These method are necessary when you implement custom touch event handling in your application for a custom object.
It allow you to clean up resources when the user stop touching your custom object or when the touches is cancelled.